# How to fill DataFrame with values based on index and column?

Tags: pandas

I need to create an empty df and fill it using function that takes column and index of every cell and returns a value to put into the cell.

```
columns = ('a', 'b', 'c')
index =  ('b', 'c', 'e')
def func(i, j):
  return i + '_' + j
df = pd.DataFrame([[func(i, j) for i in columns] for j in index], columns=columns, index=index)
```

makes

```
    a   b   c
b   a_b b_b c_b
c   a_c b_c c_c
e   a_e b_e c_e
```

another sample

```
columns = (1, 2, 3)
index =  (1, 3, 5)
def func(i, j):
  return i ** j
df = pd.DataFrame([[func(i, j) for i in columns] for j in index], columns=columns, index=index)
```

makes

```
    1   2   3
1   1   2   3
3   1   8   27
5   1   32  243
```

Now I got an empty df:

```
columns = (1, 2, 3)
index =  (1, 3, 5)
def func(i, j):
  return i + j
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=index)

    1   2   3
1   NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN
5   NaN NaN NaN
```

Is any possibility to fill it with values using something like `df.apply(   WHAT????   )` without list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the exact same logic, iterating over the index and columns:

```
df[:] = [[func(i, j) for i in df.columns] for j in df.index]
```

Trying to use `apply` wouldn't be better since it's intrinsically using a python loop.

Modified `df`:

```
   1  2  3
1  2  3  4
3  4  5  6
5  6  7  8
```

Side note: while this is not possible for all types of data/operations, if you have numeric data you could avoid the function and vectorize:

```
df[:] = df.index.to_numpy()[:, None] + df.columns.to_numpy()
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought it could be some  “vectorized” operation like df.columns * df index without iterating.

Comment: @Tatiana you can for some operations (like numeric operations), not for arbitrary functions, see my update

Comment: I see. so if I have a specific function or str data I can not avoid iteration. Thank you!